# How to save Progress in Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm making a simple game in Android Studio with a lot of layouts and the game is: When your answer is correctly you go to next Step (Next Layout), and I want to save your progress in SQLite.

There are 10 questions, if you want to stop in the third, when you open the game again you can come back to the third question. I don't wanna answer all the questions again.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: By doing a Google search, or for that matter, _any_ kind of research.

Comment: [Like this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).

Comment: [Try something](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+store+data&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS750US750&oq=android+store+data&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2256j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need a SQL database, use SharedPreferences

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
   //WHEN USER LEAVES APP SAVE PROGRESS
   SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
   editor.putInt("progress", progress);
   editor.apply();
   super.onPause();
}
```

and for retrieving the progress

```
 SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
 int progress = sp.getInt("progress");
```